# Including #foo preprocessor directives at compile time (GNU tools)

Tags: configure, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, gnu-toolchain

I've currently run in such a problem, in fact caused by the package maintainer(s), who simply did not consider that a certain preprocessor definition was not available until version X of a certain toolkit package required in the dependencies (which is currently in testing stage). It was fixable by simply adding an additional `#define` to a header file in the base system, making the project compile fine again.
However, what if I had no root access to the system? Could I also add a `#define new_macro "i am from the future"` at compile time, e. g. to `configure`?
When reading myself through the matter, I thought that it might maybe work with the `DEFS` environment variable, but apparently this is not meant to be used for C preprocessor directives.
So can this be accomplished at all?

Comment: `gcc -DSOME_MACRO="some_value"`?

Comment: Yes this would basically work, but this will require me to directly edit the `gcc` parameters, which I actually wanted to avoid. This is none the less awkward as editing the header file of the depending package directly.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `./configure CC='gcc -Dnew_macro="i am from the future"'` (syntax?) to replace the actual `gcc` command in the file with the one+parameter?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately a huge problem is the strings in quotes. Even escaping them by a backslash did not work. Not until I really hacked in the `#define` into the file in the `/usr` tree the project would finally compile. Otherwise it would always split up a constant `first-second` into `first` and `second`, breaking every function call.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, but unfortunately a huge problem is the strings in quotes

Create a file, for example at `~/somedir/mycompiler` with content:

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc -Dnew_macro="i am from the future" "$@"
```

add executable permissions `chmod +x ~/somedir/mycompiler` and then pass that as parameter to `configure`:

```
./configure CC="$HOME"/somedir/mycompiler ...
```

Configure script in turn will use that script to compile everything, passing `-D` everywhere, and quotes will be properly parsed by `sh`.